# unable to output string variable from sql result notice

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi all im currently just started with php, im currently trying to generate a string to out put on the html page but have had no much luck currently this is what i have done so far.

```
    $qry = "INSERT INTO bids VALUES (NULL,'".$_SESSION['userID']."','$productID', '".$_POST['bids']."', NOW()  )";
    $rs = $this -> db -> query($qry);
    if($rs)
    {
    //this bit checks if the database have been added or not by the value greater than 0 then we know it was successful 
        if($this -> db -> affected_rows > 0)
        {
             $msg = 'Your bid has been placed';
        }
        else
        {
             $msg = 'error in inputing the bid';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = 'Outside of $rs';
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

with the string $msg im hoping to out up that as a string on the html page.
`$html . = '$msg';` but currently it doesnt come up can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong ? why `$msg` wont show ?

Comment: Are those spaces in `$this -> db -> query($qry)` and `$this -> db -> affected_rows` in your actual code?

Comment: How are you outputting $html?

Comment: Show the code that calls this function, the problem is there.

Answer (score 4):

Here: `'$msg'` outputs `$msg` literally.

Use double quotes: `"$msg"` will output the contents of the variable `$msg`.

Or you can just directly call `$msg` with no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `return $msg;` to `echo $msg;`
One more thing, I think you have one extra '}' in the end of the code. Try to the balance braces.

Comment: I'm guessing `}` at the end is supposed to match the `function whatever () {` statement, which he didn't show.